# How to write plugin for scratch text editor from elementary os?

Tags: development, code

I've been using scratch for quite some time and its features as an IDE are very limited. So I was wondering how to develop/install new third party plugins for it but I was unable to find any documentation pertaining to it. Is it possible? If yes,then how?

Comment: This is a work in progress, but there is a blueprint for it so keep checking progress of this: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/scratch/+spec/plugin-documentation

Answer (score 4):

**Scratch** is developed in Vala, so you have at least two ways to create a plugin for a vala application:

You can use `Glib.Module` class from *gmodule-2.0* library to develop it. You can find more info at:

- [Valadoc : Glib.Module](https://valadoc.org/gmodule-2.0/GLib.Module.html)
- [TypeModules at gnome.org](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/TypeModules)

However, there is other way, used by Scratch, to add plugins: You can use *libpeas-1.0* library. You can find more info at:

- [Valadoc : libpeas-1.0](https://valadoc.org/libpeas-1.0/Peas.html)

Also, you can take a look at Scratch plugin-manager code:

- [Launchpad : Scratch](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-apps/scratch/scratch/view/head:/src/Services/PluginManager.vala)

And finally, a simple tutorial about how to develop a plugin for a vala program:

- [Getting Started with Libpeas Extensions in Vala](http://steef435.github.io/2016/01/20/getting-started-with-libpeas-extensions-in-vala/)

I hope these readings will help you with your question.

Comment: thanks for the links, I was wondering if there are existing plugins written by third party developers?

Comment: Take a look at Autovala plugin: https://github.com/rastersoft/autovala/tree/master/scratch_plugin